# Why do I get different BIC values when I use regsubsets and lm in R

Tags: r, model-selection, bic

I used `regsubsets` to find a model with lowest BIC; height is our D.V. , the code I typed is below:

```
male = read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
mreg = regsubsets(height ~ biacromial + pelvic.breadth + bitrochanteric + chest.depth 
         + chest.diam + elbow.diam + wrist.diam + knee.diam + ankle.diam 
         + shoulder.girth + chest.girth + waist.girth + navel.girth + hip.girth 
         + thigh.girth + bicep.girth + forearm.girth + knee.girth + calf.girth 
         + ankle.girth + wrist.girth + age + weight
        , data=male)
plot(mreg)
```

[image]

so the best subset for male is: `bitrochanteric,waist.girth+hip.girth+thigh.girth+bicep.girth, calf.girth+weight`

I regress the model using `lm`

```
 mreg2 = lm(height ~ bitrochanteric + waist.girth + hip.girth + thigh.girth 
             + bicep.girth + calf.girth + weight, data=male)
 BIC(reg2)
```

Then I got a value of 1461.665 ,which is totally different from my graph and so I don't understand at all why it is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just an investigation, I have never used this command before.*

The vertical axis probably means "Drop in BIC" compared to the intercept-only model, not the model BIC.

For instance, if your ideal model has a BIC of 1451.665, corresponding to a drop of 220.

Then the model with just `waist.girth` and `weight` should have a BIC of about 1551. Because that model only has a drop of 120, which is still 100 higher than your ideal model.

Here is the track of my investigation:

```
library(leaps)
b<-regsubsets(Fertility~.,data=swiss,nbest=2)
summary(b)
plot(b)
```

[image]

Now compare the best and the worst models:

```
attach(swiss)
m01 <- glm(Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality)
m02 <- glm(Fertility ~ Examination)
m03 <- glm(Fertility ~ 1)
BIC(m01)
BIC(m02)
BIC(m03)
BIC(m02) - BIC(m03)  # Should be about -18
BIC(m01) - BIC(m03)  # Should be about -37
BIC(m02) - BIC(m01)  # Difference from the models
(-18) - (-37)        # Difference taken from the axis
```

Results:

```
>     BIC(m01)
[1] 336.3417
>     BIC(m02)
[1] 355.9029
>     BIC(m03)
[1] 377.4258
>     BIC(m02) - BIC(m03)  # Should be about -18
[1] -21.52281
>     BIC(m01) - BIC(m03)  # Should be about -37
[1] -41.08403
>     BIC(m02) - BIC(m01)  # Difference from the models
[1] 19.56122
>     (-18) - (-37)        # Difference taken from the axis
[1] 19
```

Comment: BIC can take more than one model like this    `> BIC(m01,m02,m03)
    df      BIC
m01  6 336.3417
m02  3 355.9029
m03  2 377.4258`

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Thanks so much!!! This has bugged me for quite awhile, finally understand why. Thanks

Comment: @user40693, you're welcome. This function looks pretty nifty as well. Thanks for introducing it to me.