# BIC drop in regsubset summary different from manual calculation in R

Tags: r, regression, model-selection, bic

The leaps library regsubset function gives an object that contains the list of BIC drops of each subset model from the intercept model.
However, it is different from what is calculated manually.

For example, using the mtcars dataset

Reproducible code:

```
library(leaps)

# Stepwise selection
stepwise = regsubsets(mpg~., data=mtcars, method="seqrep", nvmax=10)

# Plot results to see best subset from stepwise selection is of size 3
plot(stepwise, scale="bic")

# Optimal subset size is 3
which.min(summary(stepwise)$bic)

# The variables from subset size 3 are cyl, hp and wt
coef(stepwise, 3)

# Minimum (optimal) BIC value drop from intercept model is -45.41594
min(summary(stepwise)$bic)

# Manual calculation i.e. BIC of model of 3 variables - BIC of intercept
# Gives -48.88168
BIC(lm(mpg~cyl+hp+wt, data=mtcars))-BIC(lm(mpg~1, data=mtcars))
```

Why is there such a difference (-48.9 vs -45.4)?
Roughly an absolute difference of 3.5

Refer to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87468/why-do-i-get-different-bic-values-when-i-use-regsubsets-and-lm-in-r) for BIC display values of regsubset summary, notice the use of word "about" and the discrepancies in manual and regsubset summary can be seen there too. (also around a difference of 3.5)

Comment: I would print / step through the `summary()` function (`print(leaps:::summary.regsubsets)`; `debug(leaps:::summary.regsubsets)`) and similarly for `stats:::BIC.default`, paying careful attention to the inclusion/exclusion of intercept and standard deviation in the parameter count ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think the `$bic` component is the drop in BIC from the intercept-only model. Perhaps that would be better, but it isn't, and it isn't documented to be.

You can see that the BIC differences from `summary` do match manual calcuation for all the models where `summary` computes the BIC, eg

```
> summary(stepwise)$bic[3]-summary(stepwise)$bic[1]
[1] -7.621329
> BIC(lm(mpg~cyl+hp+wt, data=mtcars))-BIC(lm(mpg~wt, data=mtcars))
[1] -7.621329
> summary(stepwise)$bic[3]-summary(stepwise)$bic[2]
[1] -10.20327
> BIC(lm(mpg~cyl+hp+wt, data=mtcars))-BIC(lm(mpg~cyl+disp, data=mtcars))
[1] -10.20327
```

If you want to calculate BIC differences for this intercept-only model it takes a bit of work to make `regsubsets` fit it. You need to specify `intercept=FALSE`, supply a column of 1s, and then increase `nvmax` enough that the model with just the intercept is chosen. Once I do that, I get

```
mtcars$one<-1
stepwise = regsubsets(mpg~., data=mtcars, method="seqrep", nvmax=10,  intercept=FALSE,nbest=5)
coef(stepwise,14)
coef(stepwise,4)
summary(stepwise)$bic[14]-summary(stepwise)$bic[4]
```

Alternatively, the BIC that `summary.stepwise` would compute for the intercept-only model with `intercept=TRUE` if it computed one is $\log n$, so

```
> log(nrow(mtcars))
> min(summary(stepwise)$bic)-log(nrow(mtcars))
[1] -48.88168
```